# How can we do theft detection in shopping malls by cctv?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem related to computer vision and machine learning. Basically we are working on video surveillance system which will be trained to detect any suspicious activity like theft or shop lifting in stores.We are confused that is that will be able to solve this problem or not. We don't know that is it feasible or not. So kindly just suggest us something. Any help will be appreciated.

While I understand that Open CV is great for face-detection and usable for face-recognition, can it be used for analyzing "actions", s.a. the act of sitting, the act of lifting an object off the shelf ? If so, what are some of these algorithms I should dig deeper into ?

Are there other libraries (other than OpenCV) which need to be used for such tasks? Are there open-source libraries for the same?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question is far too broad

Comment: There is a paper by me stating a simple stretegy on how we can detect theft based activities.
You can find a paper here:-
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-15-6876-3_34

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is currently a very active area in computer vision and machine learning research called Behaviour Analysis or Activity Detection. State of the art approaches can be found in journals like PAMI or conferences like CVPR or NIPS. As of today, it is nowhere near the performance you would require to build an automatic theft-detection system in the general case (i.e., any surveillance camera looking into any scene in any orientation). Behaviour Analysis is based on many underlying techniques, such as identifying the pose of people in images. Current research is still trying to figure out if there's a person in the picture and the position of its limbs in the general case.

Here's what might be feasible with the current research state: A system that help an operator focus on potential threats when cameras have a clear unobstructed view to a clear and mostly static environment (e.g., glass displays). An operator could therefore monitor many more cameras than before, because the system will automatically hide the cameras that clearly does not contain suspicious activity or movement.

To know more about current possibilities, I recommend you to check [the literature](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Human%20Behaviour%20Analysis%20in%20Video%20Surveillance&btnG=&hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5) (like [this example](http://mmi.tudelft.nl/pub/leon/436.pdf)), decompose the problem into subparts and leverage your priors (your a priori knowledge of the scene and people you're looking at) as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

By using object recognition (by helping deep learning) we can detect object and by using the data set of recorded object in the shop we can assess to the detailed (price) of that object. based on the number of objects and information about the object we can recognize the issue such as thrift in the counter.

Comment: You are saying about only one scenario that is theft on counter. But we want to trigger an alarm when somebody grab a product from shelf of store and then put it into his pocket.  And similar other theft activities.